# Catching continuous requests with seleniumwire

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumwire

I have a website that continuously makes AJAX requests (about 1 per second).

I would like seleniumwire to simply keep the browser open and catch all these requests, without having to refresh the page, but I couldn't find a way to do it, i.e.

```
for request in driver.requests:
    ...
```

will return the requests made while loading the page, but not all subsequent requests, even if I try to use:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

Is there a way to keep seleniumwire catching AJAX requests continuously on a loaded web page?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution myself: I need to use an interceptor:

```
def interceptor(request, response):
    print(
        request.url,
        response.status_code,
        response.headers['Content-Type']
    )

driver.response_interceptor = interceptor
```

Then I can simply do `time.sleep(1000000)` after `driver.get(...)` and wait for responses to arrive.